# I am trying to open a file by using Python but I am getting a error message

Tags: python

I am using the following path for the csv file:

```
cc_dataset = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\MO\Documents\credit.csv")
```

but I am getting the following message:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

or

```
File "C:/Users/MO/demofile.txt/untitled70.py", line 248
cc_dataset = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\MO\Documents\credit.csv")
                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Please let me know what the correct way to do this.

Comment: Replace '\' with '\\', i.e,, `"C:\Users\MO\Documents\credit.csv")` with `"C:\\Users\\MO\\Documents\\credit.csv")`

Comment: `\U` begins a unicode escape sequence in python literals. As mentioned `\\U`` fixes that.

Comment: Try using forward slashes, it's much easier and I am pretty sure it works